# How does Joomla create databases in a safe way?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

My earlier 'old' php code creates a database using the basic PHP PDO class and the mysql `'CREATE DATABASE'` command. Recently I started with Joomla 3 and the provided example application. I run all my code om mij laptop (macbook pro), e.g., localhost.

To the point: My laptop crashed and had to do a hard reset, and after that *my database created by the old code was corrupted*, e.g., had empty tables. But the database of the Joomla application was/is still okay.

I cannot believe this difference is a coincidence, so I wonder *how Joomla creates/how to create databases that provides more safety against these kind of failures?*

Appreciate your help;-)

Comment: Most likely use of innodb. Your MyISAM tables got corrupted because of hard reset, innodb on the other hand is fault tolerant and recovers automatically.

Comment: To check this, do `SHOW CREATE TABLE old_table` and look for `ENGINE=MyISAM`, then `SHOW CREATE TABLE a_joomla_table` and look for `ENGINE=InnoDB`

Comment: thnx (!) SHOW CREATE TABLE does not work anymore on the old tables as they dont seem to exist anymore - though they still appear in the list in the Phpmyadmin. The Joomla db does indeed use innodb. So I will go for Innodb in the future (!)

Comment: Hi, you can try to recover your old myisam-tables using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html